# Field is not populated by trigger AFTER INSERT

Tags: postgresql, heroku, salesforce, database-trigger

I have created trigger on `AFTER INSERT`:
[trigger in PostgreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEa6n.png)

The trigger function:
[trigger function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq9vT.png)

When I try to insert record to db the field `heroku_id__c` is not populated:
[record in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUroY.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, no images for code. Present it as (formatted) text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning to the `NEW` record only makes sense in a `BEFORE` trigger. At the time an `AFTER` trigger runs, the row has already been written, and nothing happens any more with the `NEW` record.

But do not use `RETURN NULL` in the `BEFORE` trigger unless you want to cancel the `INSERT`.